# Dynamic Carousel Indicators for Banner Rotator

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

Why are the dynamic carousel indicators not rotating with the banners?

I'm injecting a stock bootstrap carousel around an existing DIV structure. The indicators are clickable, **but they don't rotate or highlight when the indicators are clicked**

**[DEMO](http://output.jsbin.com/suquhehada)**

The few lines of custom jquery below will find `.carousel-inner` that's wrapping the DIV and append a carousel indicator for each item within the ordered list.

```
 $(".carousel-inner div.item").each(function(i) {
            $('.carousel-indicators').append("<li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='' class=''></li>");
    });
```

Finally, the custom jquery will find each list item and attach `data-slide-to` with an integer. However, I don't know why the indicators are not rotating with the banners.

```
$("ol.carousel-indicators li").attr("data-slide-to", function(i, attr) {
            $("ol.carousel-indicators li").first().addClass('active');
            return attr + (i + 0)
        });
```

Here's the full custom jquery that builds the indicators dynamically:

```
$(document).ready(function(){  
    $(".modAcTitle.modAcActive, .ac_expand").remove()  // kill this, its not needed.
    $(".modAcContent").unwrap(); //good
    $(".modAcContent").addClass('item').removeClass('modAcContent'); //fixes items
    $(".item").first().addClass('active');
    $(".carousel-inner div.item").each(function(i) {
            $('.carousel-indicators').append("<li data-target='#carousel-example-generic' data-slide-to='' class=''></li>");
    });
    $("ol.carousel-indicators li").attr("data-slide-to", function(i, attr) { // give each section its own id
        $("ol.carousel-indicators li").first().addClass('active');
        return attr + (i + 0)
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess I should have just googled it, because this is the solution.

Source: https://coderwall.com/p/4ulwtg/auto-generate-twitter-bootstap-carousel-indicators

```
<!-- auto-generate carousel indicator html -->
var myCarousel = $(".carousel");
myCarousel.append("<ol class='carousel-indicators'></ol>");
var indicators = $(".carousel-indicators"); 
myCarousel.find(".carousel-inner").children(".item").each(function(index) {
    (index === 0) ? 
    indicators.append("<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='"+index+"' class='active'></li>") : 
    indicators.append("<li data-target='#myCarousel' data-slide-to='"+index+"'></li>");
});     

<!-- then call carousel -->
$('.carousel').carousel();
```

Demo: http://output.jsbin.com/sitayikuko/